# Организация истории изменений на серверах

Tags: linux, сервер, мониторинг

Добрый день.
Задача следующая: есть около 10 серверов, работает два админа, чтобы при изменении какой нить настройки все не сломалось, было решено вести историю изменений на серверах. На подобии блога, но в котором можно сортировать инфу, например по дате или по серверу.

В гугл-доках не очень удобно, уверен есть уже что-нибудь, что придумали для нас.
 Есть у кого нить информация о подобном?

Comment: Я думаю, вам на самом деле нужен git и любой configuration manager

Answer (score 1):

Есть много разных хороших способов. И я думаю, что гуглдоки для хранения конфигов - не очень. А вот хранить всякие описания "добавили такой то параметр, посмотрим, поможет ли" или добавили это, потому что попросил Бос - самое оно. Потом легко можно будет понять, почему так а не иначе.

Один с интересных способов хранить конфиг - это хранить его прямо в git. На эту тему даже есть много статей, [Например](http://www.maratbn.com/blogs/2012/12/04/using-git-to-keep-track-of-updates-in-etc/). Этот способ решает много вопросов сразу - кто добавлял (история), почему (если комментарий прописан), какие ещё конфиги менялись (некоторые конфиги по одиночке не меняются). И можно даже в markdown формате расписывать, а gitlab/github это все красиво покажет.

Второй способ - использовать системы "доставки конфигов". Когда машин всего две - ничего страшного. А если их 500? А если машины работают на разных системах и конфиги нужно немножко "затачивать"? Для этого придумали такую систему как [puppet](https://puppet.com/) (марионетка). Вот как [его использовать](http://samag.ru/archive/article/779). Но puppet - не единственный в своем окружении - [Habr - Обзор: Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt](https://habrahabr.ru/post/211306/).

Сейчас появился ещё третий способ - докер. Это не совсем конфиги, но мало чего:)

Ещё одно направление - [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd). Но это уже больше для программистов. Это такое себе key-value хранилище (как монга или редис), но предназначенное для хранения данных на нескольких серверах (все синхронно расползается и синхронизируется). Это может быть удобно, если есть сайт и в нем админка. А сам сайт хранится на десятке серверов. Можно конечно в базу сохранить настройки, но что делать, если база упала? Или два админа с разных серверов решили конфиг поправить? А etcd поможет эту задачу решить.

Answer (score 1):

2 админа это уже команда, а учитывая распределенный характер процесса асимптотика управленческой задачи составляет 10x3x2 = 60, это существенно для менеджмента (10 серверов, 3 - средний коэффициент сложности так как управление сервером подразделяется на оборудование, ОС и прикладные системы, 2 админа).

Поэтому инструмент должен быть соответствующий - управление задачами или тикетами. На любую работу админам должен быть создан тикет (задача) с описанием, согласованными сроками, указанными объектами инфраструктуры (серверами, с детализацией - оборудование, ОС, прикладные системы и пр.). Должен существовать регламент исполнения, который включает в себя и документирование (что фактически было сделано исполнителем).

Внедрив такую систему вы получите подробное протоколирование - что когда планировалось и когда, как и кем было исполнено.

В качестве инструмента подойдёт help desk система (например [Spiceworks](https://www.spiceworks.com/free-help-desk-software/), но вообще вариантов куча) или project management система (например [Asana](https://asana.com/) или [Atlassian Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/), но вариантов опять же тьма). Старичка  Mantis не могу не вспомнить доброй памятью. Выбор будет зависеть 
от того, что вам больше приглянётся и готовы ли вы немного потратиться. IMHO так лучше взять недорогую Cloud-систему чтобы не париться с локальной установкой и администрированием, бюджет 10$-20$ в месяц на админа можно думаю наскрести ;-)

А самое главное - будет создан плацдарм для роста инфраструктуры, через какое-то время вы можете смело идти к начальству с предложением закупить еще 10 серверов и нанять еще 1 админа, так как эффективность и прозрачность процессов точно повысится ;-)