# Сохранить дифф изменений на linux системе

Tags: linux, администрирование, diff

У меня есть некоторая linux система. За время эксплуатации я проводил различные настройки: записывал конфигурационные файлы, устанавливал пакеты и т.п.. Можно ли сейчас как-то получить дифф текущего состояния системы и чистой установки? Именно дифф, а не полный бэкап всех файлов. Чтобы можно было развернуть такую же систему после установки базового образа парой команд на другом компьютере.

Comment: Вроде бы нет, но посмотрите в сторону ansible и ему подобных. Достичь цели «развернуть такую же систему» можно с его помощью.

Comment: то, что вы изложили в вопросе — это фантастика. а реальность выглядит несколько иначе: [дубликат1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/630151/178576), [дубликат2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/854104/178576)

Comment: Для сервера я бы использовал docker.
В идеале, для каждого приложения пишется Dockerfile и хранится в git-e.

Dockerfile -- пошаговая инструкция по сборке образа.
Результат каждого шага хранится как дифф.

Также можно сделать контейнер, поиграться внутри, а потом из контейнера сделать образ, т. е. шаг ручной.

Answer (score -1):

Для конфигов есть `etckeeper`

БД менеджера пакетов самодостаточна

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]